# Omnet++/INET framework: how to set and use UDP simulated applications

Tags: omnet++, inet

In our simulation we are trying to simulate LISP Mobile protocol together with INET Framework with one mobile node and one fixed node (a correspondent node which is not mobile) exchanging UDP packets. That's why we decided to use `UDPBasicApp` as simulated application and we gave it to both nodes.

The problem we see is that no a UDP packet is generated and the `initialize()` method inside `UDPBasicApp` is called more than once.

This because the addresses array inside the class is empty and so it always returns without scheduling new events.

The problem now is *how to know which are the IP addresses of the nodes* so that we can write them inside the `.ini` file. Do you know how?

Answer (score 1):

It is totally OK to use module names in the destAddress parameter (instead of IP adresses). INET can resolve that for you just like domain names are resolved in real life.

If you want to configure hostA to send data to hostB, use:

```
*.hostA.udpApp[0].destAddresses = "hostB"
```